# How do I reply to calls on my Twilio Number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've a Twilio phone number and what I'm trying to implement is whenever I receive a call to this number, I want to play some auto generated response (text or sum audio file). Going through the Twilio's python docs, I discovered TwiML which can possibly do this but I'm not able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

To play an audio file or text-to-speech to a caller you'll need to use the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) or [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) verbs.  When Twilio receives the inbound call it will make an HTTP request to a URL you've configured on your Twilio phone number.  That URL can generate and return those TwiML verbs.

So if you are using Python, an option would be to use [Flask](http://flask.org/) to create an endpoint that uses the [Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) to generate TwiML containing Play or Say.

```
from flask import Flask
import twilio.twiml

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():
    """Respond to incoming requests."""
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.say("Hello Monkey")

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You cna use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose this Flask app from your local machine to test the app.

Hope that helps.